# Custom Number Picker

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make my own number picker (I believe that is what it is called) using Java/Android.
However, I think the principles apply more to Java than Android.

I just want it to look the text below (but maybe using images instead):

```
- 5 +
```

(Where the number range is from 0 to 10)

I'm not sure if the following is the best approach to it but I kind of wrote something in pseudocode/Java and hoping on feedback on refactoring it or making it better.

I was thinking about something like

```
if(plusButton.isPressed() && buttonValue == 0) { 
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.number_zero_img) } 

else if (plusButton.isPressed() && buttonValue ==1) {
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.number_one_img)}
```

etc.... for all cases from 0 to 10 for minusButton and PlusButton but I don't think that's the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this

put all drawable in a hashmap

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer > drawables = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
drawables.put(1,R.drawable.number_one_img);
drawables.put(2,R.drawable.number_two_img);
//add asll drawables like this
```

Finally on invocation do this like

```
// on plusButton pressed
image.setImageResource(drawables.get(buttonValue))
```

Also you need to manually check if it going out of bounds or else youll set null as `ImageResource` for `image`

Comment: What do you mean by check if it's going out of bounds? I want to make it so far the user can only click up to 10 or lowest to 0. It can't exceed those values.

Comment: for this conditions you need to make a check for both and set the image resource. like if the buttonValue < 0 set `buttonValue = 0` & `image.setImageResource(drawables.get(0))`. Same for >10

Comment: [Relevant alternative to HashMaps](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html), or use an Array(List).

Comment: Ah good point Panther! Btw, I just realized maybe I don't need images for the numbers but I can probably use a textView and change the number dynamically that way. (Hereby only having two images, one for minus and one for plus).

Comment: yup, `SparseArray` came into my mind but i guess he wanted to set different image resource and also reset the value to the boundary for out of bound values like going above 10 and below 0. as mentioned in previous comment

Comment: Would the above change if instead of images, I wanted to change the numbers as text? So I would use a textView instead of imageView?

Comment: If u want to change that, there is no need of this. All you need is bounds checking. You can change the text appearance by font style etc,

Comment: @Panther, Actually, I think I understand the setup but I don't understand how to increment and decrement between the values. In this case, how would I setup the buttonvalue? How do I know if I start with 0 and increase by 2, and then decrease by 1, that I will get 1 and not another number?

Comment: Setup a textwatcher for the textview and in afterTextChanged check the bounds condition. This will handle the bounds condition always. For up button increase the existing value and replace it by 1 up, and for reduce detuct 1. If the user manually enters a value afterTextChanged will take care of the bounds value. Hope this explains

Comment: @Panther, I have a problem with the way I have it set up right now. See new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26616562/number-picker-gets-stuck-when-set-at-0