# Number picker gets stuck when set at 0

Tags: java, android

Here's the code I have so far:

```
            final ImageView plus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_sign);
            final ImageView minus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.minus_sign);


            final int[] counter = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
            final TextView num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num);

            plus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (plus_button.isPressed()) {

                        if ((counter[0] <= 9) && (counter[0] >= 0)) {

                            counter[0]++;
                            num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                        }
                    }

                }
            });

            minus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    if (minus_button.isPressed()) {
                        counter[0]--;

                        if ((counter[0] <= 9) && (counter[0] >= 0)) {

                            num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

This displays something like a number picker(?) or number incrementer/decrementer.

Like
    - number +

where number is a range from 0 to 10. If you click on "-", the number decrements, and if you click on plus "+" number increments.

The above code mostly works but I noticed a few strange things:

1)The picker is blank at first like this: 
     -    +

with no number set inside. When I click on "plus" I want it to show 0 but instead it shows 1. So I think it's supposed to show 0 at first but instead it shows blank. Not sure why?

2)I can increment all the way to 10 by click on the "plus" sign starting from 1 but when I go down to zero, I can't go back up the number list. I'm not sure why this occurs?

edit: This occurs if I click on the minus button twice after I hit 0.

3) How can I get the specific number that the picker is set at from the way I have it coded above? For ex. if the user sets it to 5, how can I know that the user set the picker to 5? Is there a way to find out?

EDIT: Here's the newly edited code:

```
final ImageView plus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.plus_sign);
                final ImageView minus_button = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.minus_sign);


                final int[] counter = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
                final TextView num = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.num);
                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));

                plus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (plus_button.isPressed()) {

                            if ((counter[0] <= 9) && (counter[0] >= 0)) {

                                counter[0]++;
                                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                                System.out.println(num.getText().toString());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });

                minus_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        if (minus_button.isPressed()) {

                            if ((counter[0] <= 9) && (counter[0] >= 0)) {
                                counter[0]--;
                                num.setText(Integer.toString(counter[0]));
                                System.out.println(num.getText().toString());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) it starts the way it does because you didn't set anything for it at first. You could do something like num.setText(Integer.toString(counter [0])); right after calling it by its id. Notice that you only set some text to num when you increase or decrease

2) I believe it's related with the fact that you substract no matter what. You should have the subtract operation inside your second if statement. The way you have it right now it allows you to go as far as you want before zero, but it won't show because your if evaluates if it's greater than or equal to zero, and because it's not, it doesn't show

3) Not sure what you mean, but you could do num.getText().toString() and parse it to an integer or keep it like that. That will get you what's on your num textview when you call it

Comment: Can you elaborate on number 2 or give me an example? Number 3 works, thank you.

Comment: You are subtracting only if the minus button is pressed, you're not considering that it might already be zero. Suppose it's set to 0, you press and it's set to -1, but the next if in your minus method says that if num >=0 then it should be displayed. Just put the counter[0]--; sentence inside your second if. Thus your variable counter[0] won't be able to have any value smaller than zero

Comment: ohhh I see. Thank you lol :D I didn't catch that before but now it's showing -1. I don't want to see -1 but only 0.

Comment: What do you by calling it's id for number 1?

Comment: You've already done that, when you called findViewById(), and as you already have your counter array initialized you should write num.setText(integer.toString(counter[0])) beneath the findViewById line

Comment: Thanks btw. I realized something: now it's showing -1. I don't want to see -1 but only 0 when I put the counter-- inside the if statement.

Comment: Ok change counter[0]>=0 for counter[0]>0 because now it's substracting also when it's 0

Comment: You are right it works. Now it just gets stuck on the end when I set it to 10 and click twice on the plus sign lol. Why does this happen?

Comment: Replace 9 by 10 in the minus click

Comment: wats the use of counter array ?? :-/